# spacemacs keys to move up or down org-mode need to be remapped

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, spacemacs

I use `spacemacs` version 0.200.9, and I totally love it. One issue that I have though is when using `org-mode.` I can't seem to move different levels of the hierarchy up and down as I used to be able to do with the `Alt-up` or `Alt-down` key like I used to. I also use the `i3wm` windows manager, so I think that that these two `Alt` keys are mapped to the windows manager instead of to emacs.

In spacemacs these shortcuts to move subtree up and down are defined below.

```
SPC m S l   org-demote-subtree
SPC m S h   org-promote-subtree
SPC m S k   org-move-subtree-up
SPC m S j   org-move-subtree-down
```

However for some reason these do not seem to work for me either.

So I suppose I need to directly define the keymapping for these 4 features. But I was not sure of the proper way to do that.

I found this issue posted on the spacemacs site.

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/3018

I added the following code to my `.spacemacs` file, but it did not work

```
  (evil-define-key 'normal evil-org-mode-map
    "SPC o i" 'org-move-subtree-up
    "SPC o m" 'org-move-subtree-down
    "SPC o j" 'org-promote-subtree
    "SPC o k" 'org-demote-subtree)
```

Can anyone indicate where the error is, or why I can't seem to get org-mode to move org-mode subtrees up or down? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Peripherally related - I also use Spacemacs and i3wm, and since Emacs heavily relies on Meta (Alt), I would suggest a different i3 leader key if it's not too engrained in your brain. I use Super instead, and it works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

When defining keybindings, if in doubt, wrap them in `kbd` ie. `(kbd "SPC o i")`. However spacemacs defines `spacemacs/set-leader-keys` which enables just `(kbd "oi")` as your binding.

If you try doing `M-:` and run `(org-move-subtree-up)` with an org heading on point and it works but your bindings don't, then that means your bindings were incorrect.